# tidyr VS dplyr + reshape2

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, reshape2

Is there any advantages or limitations of using `reshape2` in association to `dplyr` rather than fully using `tidyr`?

I am not completely familiar with the `tidyr` equavalent of `reshape2` functions and I would like to understand what would be the reason to switch to `tidyr` only as I see it more and more in R codes.

Comment: This is fairly opinion-based: tidyr’s API is an evolution of reshape2’s, and it more closely matches that of dplyr and related packages, especially when it comes to computation on the language (non-standard evaluation). Furthermore, the tidyr package does *more* than reshape2 ((un-)nesting, separating and merging columns, splitting values into separate rows …). It’s definitely worth learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tidyr follows the `tidyverse` conventions, like `dplyr`:

- functions designed to work well with pipes `%>%`
- non-standard evaluation (NSE), which means you use unquoted column names rather than strings
- `rlang` tidy dots semantics, like other tidyverse packages, which means you can use `!!` and `!!!` which are very powerful once you know how to use them. Of course, you can do the same without fancy syntax if you don't use functions with NSE... but if you already use `dplyr` you're already using NSE everywhere.

If you already use `dplyr`, your code may look more consistent if you also use `tidyr` for data reshaping.

Besides, `reshape2` focuses on reshaping data (`melt/cast`) while `tidyr` does this (`gather/spread`) and more like manipulating columns (`unite/separate/extract`), creating and working with list-columns and nested data/frames (`nest/unnest`), dealing with missing values (`complete/expand/fill`).

I should also say that `dplyr` and `tidyr` are complementary, so I would challenge your frame `(tidyr)` VS `(dplyr + reshape2)`. `dplyr` is indispensible whether you work with `tidyr` or `reshape2`.

Ultimately, `melt/dcast` is equivalent to `gather/spread`, so it is a personal preference until you need the other `tidyr` features, or if you want to follow the "`tidyverse` trend".